# Prove that for all $p\in M$ there's an $M$-open set $p\in U\subset M$ and $\varepsilon >0$ such that $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\times U\subset D$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

I'm reading the book ["Introduction to Differential Geometry"](https://people.math.ethz.ch/%7Esalamon/PREPRINTS/diffgeo.pdf) written by J.W. Robbin and D.A. Salamon.

In the page 41 (Lemma 2.4.10) there's the following assertion:

> Suppose that $M\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a smooth submanifold and
> $X:M\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a smooth vector field. Define for all $p\in M$:
>
> $$\color{red}{I_X(p)}:=\bigcup \big\{I\subset \mathbb{R} \,
>  (\text{open interval}):\text{there's a integral curve }\gamma \in
>  M^I\text{ of }X\text{ such that }\gamma (0)=p\big\}.$$
>
> Then for all $p\in M$ there exists an $M$-open neighborhood
> $U_p\subseteq M$ of $p$ and a constant $\varepsilon _p>0$ such that
> $(-\varepsilon _p,\varepsilon _p)\times U_p\subseteq D:=\bigcup _{p\in
>  M}I_X(p)\times \{p\}$.

I tried to show that $U_p:=\big\{q\in M:I_X(q)=I_X(p)\big\}$ is open in $M$ because if this is true then that assertion is also true. However I failed  and I don't know how to prove that assertion.

Probably this is a consequence of a known theorem about ordinary differential equations, however I didn't study about ODE yet. I say this because, given a parametrization $\psi :V\to \psi [V]\subseteq M$ of $M$, we can define $f:V\to \mathbb{R}^n$ by $f(x):=(d\psi )_x^{-1}\circ X\circ \psi (x)$ (which is smooth) and guarantee the existence of integral curves of $X$ with the system $\begin{cases}\dot{x}=f(x)\\x(0)=p\in \psi [V]\end{cases}$ and using the Picard-Lindelöf Theorem.

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Yes to the reduction to a chart. Then, look up a proof of Picard-Lindelöf and check that you can apply the constructions of local neighborhoods there with some minimal tweaks to all IC in a small neighborhood of the given IC. (The use of only $p$ in the statement of the claim is confusing, as it is sometimes a fixed/observed point and at other times the running variable in a union.)